# regex certain character notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Let me get this short.
I have this document:

=================================

```
Dealer PIN 57FG2119 Malaysia. ID [2DF88565] Filiphine. BBM  : 5B7AF062
LINE  :agungpra.
No hp:082187754243
Open agen, reseller & dropship
CS 1 : PIN 5353ABC2
CS 2 : SMS 085711439997
Fb : Griya Madinah
Fanpage : Madinah butik
Email : madinah_butik@ymail.com
Dermastore Group
Stokis VVIP Indonesia 100% Original
Pemesanan/konsultasi:
5A66BC4D (BBM) 081320232353 (SMS) 08114530052 (WA) @dermastorecoid (LINE)
*Viciadas em Moda, Maquiagem, Unhas Comprinhas, Viagens*ABC-SP
blogviciadasemcompras@gmail.com
```

================================

As we see. There's some pin BB. 8 pin BB characters. I'm looking for a REGEX formula which be able to sort/save/block/keep all 8 characters and delete the rest. So the final result will be like this. Pin BB only. 8 characters only (with automatically have the enter or space of each line)

```
57FG2119 
2DF88565
5B7AF062
5353ABC2
5A66BC4D
```

I'm really blank on it. Really I need a help. Thank you.

Comment: A note on markdown formatting: use triple backtick \`\`\` instead of repeated equal sign to mark the beginning and end of a preformat area.

Comment: @downvoters try to format the code instead of asking op to do that since he is new to SO.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I was in the middle of doing that, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj  Most of those downvotes were automatic from spam flags, and personally I'm still not convinced.

Comment: Try [`\b([0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]{7})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/aC9zU7/1)

Comment: @Joe, Avinash Raj
I know all admin of stackoverflow are kind and generous. And I admit that I'm tooooooo lazy just to do a formatting. I'm in hurry and please forgive me.

Comment: @Tushar, you saved my life. That's what I'm looking for. But what is after that? Inverse Bookmark?

Answer (score 2):

You actually can do this in a single regex.

In Notepad++'s find-replace:

- Regex: [`.*?\b([0-9A-Z]{8})\b(?(?=.*?\b[0-9A-Z]{8}\b)|.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/mP3jU3/1)
- Replace With: `$1\n`
- Select "Match Case", "Regular Expression", and ". matches newline"
- Replace All

[image]

This basically says "match a pin; if there are more pins after it leave them for the next match otherwise just consume the rest of the junk (i.e. tail of file after last pin)".

The regex `.*?\b([0-9A-Z]{8})\b|.*` works as well, it is a bit simpler but will leave a blank line at the end (there the `|.*` at the end matches the last bit of the input if no more pins are found).

For more info check out [Notepad++'s regex support](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).

In your sample input the output is:

```
57FG2119
2DF88565
5B7AF062
5353ABC2
5A66BC4D
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in a single regex..

Step 1: In Notepad++, press CTRL+H and check Search Mode 'Regular expression' below..

Step 2: Check 'Match case' and 'Wrap around'

Step 3: Fill 'Find what' box entry with

```
  \b([0-9A-Z]{8})\b
```

Step 4: Fill 'Replace with' entry with

```
  $1\n
```

Step 5: Click 'Replace All'

Step 6: Again fill 'Find what' box entry with

```
  [\w\W]*?\b([0-9A-Z]{8})\b
```

Step 7: And fill 'Replace with' box with

```
  $1\n
```

Step 8: Click 'Replace All'

Now you have your BB pins

[image]

Comment: I thank you for your reply but I am sorry, 0 occurences were replaced /:)

Comment: Please remove any spaces before regex if any.. I have checked and its working fine.. Click Find Next to check if it gets selected

Comment: After step 4 you must click replace all.

Comment: @Jason C, gzix, I owe you two a good deed in return. Really really I thank you so much! :'(

Comment: @near89 You can accept any of the two answers if you have got your solution